# VS.net 2013 Community Edition - Install Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I downloaded CPT 3 of the Apache tools but inside Visual Studio.Net 2013 Community Edition it still say "Install Tools for Apache Cordova" in the New Project window.

I have Update 4 installed and the latest Windows 8.1 updates etc.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed CPT3, had to run Update 4 again in Repair and then after a system reboot was the templates etc visible in Visual Studio.Net 2013 Community Edition.